# How to properly export from Illustrator to Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, layers, export

And by that I mean that each layer with sublayers in AI should become a group in PS.

Answer (score 4):

#### File → Export... → Photoshop (psd)

Check '**Write Layers**'

[image: Photoshop Export Options from Adobe Illustrator]

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but it did not transform the illustrator groups in photoshop groups.

Comment: Are you using groups or layers? Your question specified "layers" (as does the export dialog), not groups. The export will only export *layers*.

Comment: Actually... I just tested and it should export groups to layers too.

Answer (score -3):

copy all group from illustrator with **ctrl + c**, go to photoshop press **ctrl +v** , than select smart object.

Comment: Although you describe a quick and efficient way of exporting from Illustrator, it doesn't do it in the way asked in the question.